# Why does Cloudflare accept SSL certificates with a domain mismatch?

Tags: cloudflare

I've noticed strange behavior with cloudflare and mismatching origin SSL certificates.

With encryption set to Full (Strict):

With CF proxy off:

- CNAME `www.my-site.com` -> `my-site.com`
- CNAME `my-site.com` -> `google.com`

Result:

- `www.my-site.com` gives certificate mismatch error (expected)
- `my-site.com` gives certificate mismatch error (expected)

Whereas, with CF proxy on:

- CNAME `www.my-site.com` -> `my-site.com`
- CNAME `my-site.com` -> `google.com`

Result

- `www.my-site.com` gives 526 error (expected)
- **`my-site.com` loads `google.com` <- Why does cloudflare accept google.com's certificate as valid for my site?**